# Currency Symbol given by DecimalFormat looks invalid

Tags: java

I face the below problem in java 8

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

class NumberTest5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale loc = new Locale("sr","ME");
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(loc);
        System.out.println("\n"+"currencySymbol:"+df.getPositivePrefix()+"\tlength:"+df.getPositivePrefix().length());
        //here the above result is currencySymbol:  €+(non breakable space char)
        //length:2     
    }
}
```

the real question is why there is an extra character appended to the currency symbol ..?

why the above program behaves in this way ...?.

what is the problem in it & how to rectify it ..?

Thanks

Comment: I ran your program as is and get output as **currencySymbol:€  length:2** on Windows 8.1 , JDK 1.8 and Eclipse Luna. So i guess you need to specify other system details than JDK version.

Comment: @SabirKhan. My result is the same as op. With openjdk 1.8, linux.

Comment: It's not a "non breakable space char". It's a regular space. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/kPb8yf).

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your effort :)  it is a not breakable space char in java8 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not invalid.

The following

```
Locale loc = new Locale("sr","ME");
```

represents the `Locale` for Serbian in Montenegro. I can't find the equivalent for Java, but [here](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/sr_ME/)'s a description of this locale for glibc. Under *Currency*, you'll notice `Space separation between symbol and value` is set to `1`, indicating that

> a space separates the symbol from the value

Therefore, if you formatted a value, for example

```
System.out.println(df.format(123.45));
```

you'd get

```
€ 123,45
```

with a space between the currency symbol at the value.

That's what the *positive previx* represents.

Comment: Or said another way: Because that's how they want it in Montenegro.

Answer (score 0):

The getPositivePrefix() method will return a string with the currency symbol and a space character--They do this in order to have the currency symbol and the value separated.

You do not want the space character?
You can do two things:

---

### Solution 1

```
String symbol = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getCurrencySymbol();
    System.out.println("\n"+"currencySymbol:"+ symbol + "500\tlength:"+symbol.length());
```

Output:

```
currencySymbol:€500 length:1
```

---

### Solution 2

Add a backspace escape sequence: '\b', this will delete the space during print. But the string length size will remain when calling the length() method

```
String symbol = df.getPositivePrefix();
    System.out.println("\n"+"currencySymbol:" + symbol +"\b500\tlength:"+symbol.length());
```

Output:

```
currencySymbol:€500 length:2
```